# create dynamic Confirm dialog in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I need create dynamic confirmDialog. I have a dynamicallly created CommandButton. So when it press, confirmDialog will show. I do not know how to show it on CommandButton pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button should be like this:

```
<p:commandLink oncomplete="confirmation.show()"  
  action="#{campagneComtroller.messageDeleteCam1(c)}" 
  update=":frmDlgDel:confirmDialog">
  <p:graphicImage value="/image/delete.png" height="20" width="20"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Your confirmDialog should be like this:

```
<h:form id="frmDlgDel">
            <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" 
                    message="#{campagneComtroller.messageDeleteCam1}"  
                       header="#{bundles.messages['message.SupprimerGeneral']}" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">  
               <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="#{bundles.messages['message.OuiSure']}" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" update=":formCam :frmDlgDel"
                        actionListener="#{campagneComtroller.deleteCam1()}" />  
               <p:commandButton id="decline" value="NonPasEncore" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />   
           </p:confirmDialog>
        </h:form>
```

Your java code should be like this:

```
   public void messageDeleteCam1(Cam cam) {
conditionVerified = true; // ... you can put here your treatments
            if (conditionVerified) {
                messageDeleteCam1 = "this cam is bla bla bla ";
            } else {
                messageDeleteCam1 = "are you sure to delete this cam ?";
            }
        }
```

**NB**: we have used here ***oncomplete + update***, that's why we could see the difference in the confirmDialog after java treatments.