# Create dialog window in JSF

Tags: jsf-2.2

I would like to create a usual dialog window:

- The user clicks a link or button
- The screen becomes blackish, a new window appears (a `DIV` is created)
- By using Ajax, the `DIV` is populated with a `form.xhtml`
- By clicking on a cross in the `DIV`, the `DIV` is removed and the blackish screen too.

I know how to do some of this stuff with usual CSS/Jquery. However, I am lost on how the JSF link/button should call the Jquery code to create the dialog (because I am supposing that JSF cannot do it alone) and make the Ajax call to get the form.

I am not using [auxiliary libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030715/create-dynamic-confirm-dialog-in-jsf).

Comment: But can you start using them (libraries)? :-) Stuff like this is very easy with PF

Comment: Preferably not... Is it too difficult? If so, how could I use, for example, Omnifaces for this, would it help?